# how to visualize the DNN or CNN model with the values of the input and output layers?

Tags: python, keras, graphviz, image-graphviz

I have applied visualization to the DNN model, but the image just contains a dense layer Without the value of the input and output layers!
The code below explains the visualization process without any error, I tried to show the values of the input and output layers in image.

```
import pandas as pd
.
. 
tf.keras.utils.plot_model
.
.
def create_model():

model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(n_features))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(51, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(68, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(85, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(85, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(68, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(51, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='Adam', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file='model_combined.png')
#model.summary()
return model    

#I have tried to use 
#from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
# but i found this error : TypeError: 'InputLayer' object is not iterable
# so i use the above library to implement visualization without any error.
```

Please note that I have downloaded all of these libraries: Graphviz, pydot, pydotplus, python-graphviz

Comment: Did you try: 
`from keras.utils import plot_model;
import pydot;
plot_model(model, to_file='model.png',show_shapes=True);`

Comment: Also, on IPython notebook, I have used this before: `from IPython.display import SVG;

from keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot;

SVG(model_to_dot(model1_bg).create(prog='dot', format='svg'));`

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa, after apply the first solution, This error appears: 'InputLayer' object is not iterable!

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa, the sconed solution, also appears the same previous error : TypeError: 'InputLayer' object is not iterable

Comment: You need to at least provide the size in input layer. Alternatively, you can remove the input layer and mention the size/dimension of inputs in 1st layer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208133/discussion-between-bashar-and-ashwin-geet-dsa).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Netron](https://netron.app/) app?
It can be used to visualize the DNN or CNN model with the values of the input and output layers.

Here you can find all the [details](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron)